# File Encryption without adding a password?

Tags: file, encryption, passwords, exe

I want to encrypt a file without adding a password to it. My anti-virus will not stop blocking the file even though it's non-malicious. I heard you can encrypt the .exe file without binding a password to it so anti-virus will not detect it using programs already out there. However all the encryption programs I've used force you to encrypt with a password. If worse comes to worse I will just turn off the ant-virus whenever I am running the exes.  Thanks in advance!

Comment: Doesn't your AV support whitelists?

Comment: Yes but I don't want to have to keep doing it to every clients PC. Encrypting it would allow me to do it once and not worry.

Comment: What's the reason you don't want a password?

Comment: Ease of use mostly. I don't want to enter a password every time I want to run the exe. Also I may want to automate it soon by using the robot class in java and it would be faster/easier to just have it open the exe without having to enter a password.

Comment: @LukeWorthing: And how do you know that this will fool the antivirus software?

Comment: Encrypted with password fools anti virus I don't see why one without a password wouldn't work